# What happens when I insert empty column families in cassandra. How many memtables and sstables will be created?

Tags: cassandra

What happens when I insert empty column families in **cassandra**.  How many **memtables** and **sstables** will be created ?

Comment: You mean, create table with no data?

Comment: yes I am inserting empty records with only row key and no value.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how many inserts you will perform, because you still need to keep the data for primary key in the memory, even if all other columns are empty... SSTables will be generated when your data fill memtable, or when you issue `nodetool flush` command.